# What do you call the process of resolving the subject of a conjunct?

Tags: computational-linguistics, conjunctions

I have the sentence

```
We kick ass and take names.
```

Running this sentence through Google's dependency parser gives:

[image]

As you can see, "we" is tagged as the subject of "kick". However "we" is not tagged as the subject of "take". In order to extract this fact from the above graph, I would have to deduce it from the following:

- "take" is a conjunct of "kick"
- "take" does not have its own subject, and so must share the subject of "kick"

Does the above deduction have a name in computational lingustics, in the vein of named entity recognition or coreference resolution? I'd like to learn more about the process and see if there are any libraries that do it.

(And if you know of any libraries, please tell me :))

Comment: In generative syntax the phenomenon is known as [*Conjunction Reduction*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78109/15299), and is stated as a rule which relates sentences like your examples to conjoined clauses with repeated constituents like _We kick ass and we take names_. This may or may not be useful to you in a computational context. But there's a vast literature on the topic.

Comment: @jlawler That would make a good answer!

Comment: Here's [a list of similar rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) (also called "transformations" or "alternations"). There are several different kinds, with some [general constraints on them](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html). To find out more, see [McCawley 1998](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English.html).

Comment: In "We [kick ass] and [take names]" the two bracketed elements are a coordination of two verb phrases. It's as simple as that.